# How to execute ORACLE stored procedure from yii application?

Tags: php, oracle, stored-procedures, yii

i want to create a stored procedure which gets array of strings as inputs and returns the rows and return the data to the UI using (Yii)php. I have googled and came to a conclusion that using refcursor we can return data in row type.mentioned in

[[http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/fuecks-sps-095636.html][1]](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/fuecks-sps-095636.html%5d%5b1%5d)

like the following

```
 create PROCEDURE latest(
    num_entries_in IN NUMBER,
    entries_cursor_out OUT cursorType
) AS

    BEGIN

        OPEN entries_cursor_out FOR
            SELECT * FROM blogs WHERE rownum < num_entries_in
            ORDER BY date_published DESC;

    END latest;
```

but the problem is i want to bind cursor data in yii framework or how can i execute that stored procedure from yii and to get the respone of that query executed ?

Answer (score 0):

In your `protected/config/config.php` configure data base.

```
'db'=>array
(
    'class'=>'CDbConnection',
    'connectionString'=>'oci:dbname=dbhost:dbport/orcl;charset=UTF8'
    'username'=>'###',
    'password'=>'###',
),
```

For calling stored procedure, add this code in your model/controller.

```
$command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand('call latest(num_entries_in,entries_cursor_out )');
$command->execute();
print_r($command->queryRow());
```